# Has anyone used window.postmessage in Java selenium framework?

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, mobile-safari

Safari browser's same origin policy stops entering data inside an iFrame of different origin. We can bypass it for local safari by changing the preferences of safari. But I haven't found a way to bypass in iOS devices via Browserstack.

One solution was to navigate to the iframe URL and execute the data and get back, this is now not possible as we have a nested iFrame structure and each field is an iFrame.

Has anyone used javascript executor and tried window.postmessage() in Java selenium framework please give an example.